# PHP : get data from 2 bracket

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I want to get data from bracket in array

```
$x = ['1(data1(data2))','2(data3(data4))'];<br>
```

I want x to show :

```
$x = ['data1(data2))','data3(data4)']<br><br>
```

When i use

```
explode("(",rtrim($x,")"));
```

It show me

```
$x = ['data1','data3']
```

I am beginner of php

```
$x = ['1(data1(data2))','2(data3(data4))'];`<br>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If all your array-elements start with a number followed by a '(' and end with a ')' you could use following code:

```
$x = ['1(data1(data2))','2(data3(data4))'];

function cutSomeData($elem){
    $data = substr($elem, strpos($elem, '(')+1);
    $data = substr($data, 0, strrpos($data, ')'));
    return $data;
}
$x = array_map('cutSomeData', $x);
```

If not, let me know.
I'll try to help you out